# Based upon the first table speciality get all records with the same speciality in second table

Tags: sql

I have two tables

- doctorregistration
- patientregistration

Based upon the `doctorregistration` speciality, I want to get all patients who are having same speciality.

For example: in `doctorregistration` & `patientregistration` tables, I have a `speciality` column.

If `doctorspeciality` is DENTIST, I want to get all the patients who are registered with `speciality` as DENTIST in `patientregistration` table.

DOCTORSPECIALITY:

```
CREATE TABLE doctorRegistration
(
    speciality VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    fname      VARCHAR(15),
    lname      VARCHAR(15),
    mailid     VARCHAR(39),
    gender     VARCHAR(10),
    mobile     VARCHAR(10),
    dob        VARCHAR(25),
    country    VARCHAR(15),
    password   VARCHAR(10)
);
```

PATIENTREGISTRATION:

```
CREATE TABLE patientRegistration
(
    speciality VARCHAR(20),
    fname      VARCHAR(15),
    lname      VARCHAR(15),
    mailid     VARCHAR(39) PRIMARY KEY,
    gender     VARCHAR(10),
    mobile     VARCHAR(10),
    dob        VARCHAR(25),
    country    VARCHAR(15),
    password   VARCHAR(10)
);
```

Comment: Kindly remove other tags which are not relevant.

Comment: I removed incompatible database tags. Tag the one you are really using.

Comment: You should provide sample data and desiredresults.

Answer (score 1):

You may looking for simple INNER JOIN

```
SELECT *
FROM DoctorRegistration doc
INNER JOIN PetientRegistration p ON doc.speciality = p.speciality
```

Comment: If i execute the above query .The cross records are displaying i.e duplicate rows displaying in two tables...EX: if i have 4 cardiology recods in doctor table & i have 3 record in patient table.............It is displaying to tal 12 records instead of displaying 3 record in the patient table

Comment: @suresh: if you want to get answers that solve your problem, you need to provide more details in your question. Please **[EDIT](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41978660/edit)** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)